# Outlook Inbox Folder Parent always returns 0 Folders

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, mailitem

I have a problem with my office vsto add-in. Whenever I try to loop through all the Email Folders to get their emails I always get 0 items and I don't really know why. Here is my code :

```
var inbox = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

if (inbox is Outlook.Folder)
{
    if (inbox.Parent is Outlook.Folder)
    {
        for (int i = (inbox.Parent as Outlook.Folder).Items.Count; i > 0; i--)
        {       
            if ((inbox.Parent as Outlook.Folder).Items[i] is Outlook.MailItem)
            {
                if (((inbox.Parent as Outlook.Folder).Items[i] as Outlook.MailItem).Subject.ToString() == "test")
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It passes through the first two checks,  but in the loop

> (inbox.Parent as Outlook.Folder).Items.Count

always returns 0, even though there is plenty of emails in my Inbox. Any idea why that happens?

//

When I try to access them with .Folders instead of .Items changing the loop like this but leaving everything else untouched :

```
for (int i = (inbox.Parent as Outlook.Folder).Folders.Count; i > 0; i--){}
```

, I get an exception :

> (inbox.Parent as Outlook.Folder).Folders.Count = '(inbox.Parent as Outlook.Folder).Folders.Count' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

Just to clarify things : The goal is to loop through every folder accessing the i'th mail of each of those folders and checking if its title is "test". I know this example doesn't make much sense out of context, so let's focus only on the part that brings be trouble which is properly counting all the folders.

//

[image]

Comment: you seem to be counting the inboxes parent... not the inbox

Comment: Oh yes because I have to access all the folders, not just the main inbox. Edited.

Comment: right but parent of inbox usually does have no items in it......

Comment: Then how do I access all the folders if not through inbox parent items?

Comment: What if you use `Folders` rather than `Items` to get the sub-folders of the parent?

Comment: Your code is purely looking for items, not folders - if you were looking for folders you got very lost along the way

Comment: If I use .Folders instead, I get an exception. It's in the thread. I thought Items are basically Folders in Parent, so thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: Edited thread to include the line I meant.

Comment: Edited the thread to include the error.

Comment: It was (inbox.Parent as Outlook.Folder). Accessing it with .Folders or .Items throws the exception.

Comment: No it doesn't. It throws an exception immediately which I just realised, but the error shows up as a local when insepcting (inbox.Parent as Outlook.Folder).Items, the .Items part. Debugging doesn't stop. Accessing it with .Folders appears to be counting up to i = 23 items and then throwing an error, accessing it with .Items throws an error immediately and thus i = null.

Answer (score 1):

I made everything overly complicated by accessing olFolderInbox and then finding its parent to count the inbox folders. And while it's probably possible to do it that way, it can also be done much more easily with this one simple line :

```
var foldersCount = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Folders.Count;
```

and access specific folders by looping through the foldersCount and accessing Folders[i].